# Pascal: check multiple things in one if (like || in other languages)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I have recently started learning pascal, but I have a problem. Is it possible to do something like this (`n` is an integer):

```
if (n[1] + n[2] = n[3] + n[4]) || (n[1] + n[3] = n[2] + n[4])
```

In other languagles you can use `||`, but I can't find a way in Pascal...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C like `||` *logical OR* operator equals to `or` in Pascal based languages, so write:

```
if (n[1] + n[2] = n[3] + n[4]) or (n[1] + n[3] = n[2] + n[4]) then
```

Comment: `|` is not like `||`, single pipe forces a complete evaluation of the expressions while double pipes return true from the first expression whiuch evaluates to true (lazy bool evaluation). Isn't `or` like the single pipe ?

Comment: @user3661500 in C the `|` pipe represents the [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) while the `||` represents the [logical (boolean) or](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction). In Pascal both operations use the `or` operator and the exact type of operation is determined from the types of arguments. For instance for variables of type `Boolean` the `or` means logical or while for variables of type `Integer` the `or` means bitwise or

Comment: the OP does not specify the C-like lang. of his code sample. in D (C syntax), double pipe is as said previously. There is an ambiguity in the Q.

Comment: Free Pascal does short boolean evaluation by default. Full evaluation can be turned on by directive {$B+} or selecting certain language mode (ISO Pascal which did full by default). http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/ref/refsu5.html